# Delete Query needs refresh

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a simple page that allows me to remove bookmarks. For example, I have a table called bookmarks that holds a user_id and car_id.  It also has a remove button that when pressed, deletes the specified row from DB.

Everything works on the back end, but there is odd behavior because I need to refresh the page for the first and last operation delete to disappear from the page. The rest work fine.

**Routes.php**

```
// bookmarks
Route::any('bookmarks/del/{cid}', [
    'as' => 'bookmark_profile_path',
    'uses' => 'BookmarkController@del_bookmark'
    ]);
```

**Controller**

```
public function del_bookmark($cid)
{
    $query = DB::table('bookmarkz')->where('user_id', Auth::User()->user_id)->get();
    $rows = $query;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if($row->car_id == $cid) 
            {
                DB::table('bookmarkz')->where('car_id', '=', $cid)->delete();
                echo "Bookmark Removed";        
            }     
        }
        return View::make('user/bookmarks')->with('query',$query);  
}
```

**View**

```
@extends('...layout.layout')

@section('content')

  <h2>Bookmarks!</h2>
  <p>Your user ID is: {{ Auth::user()->user_id }}</p>

             @foreach ($query as $query_i)  
                    <table><tr>
                        <td>{{$query_i->car_id}} </td>
                        <td>
                        {{HTML::linkRoute('bookmark_profile_path', "Remove Bookmark", array($query_i->car_id))}}
                        </td>
                    </tr></table>
            @endforeach
  <div>
        {{ HTML::linkRoute('profile', 'Back to Profile') }}
        <br>
  </div>

@stop
```

Here is what happens when I press **remove bookmark** for 10018
[image]
In the database, 10018 IS deleted, also "bookmark removed" is outputted, but it still shows on the screen. If I refresh the page, it goes away.

Next, I click **remove bookmark** for 10019. Here is the result.
[image]
After I do this, 10018 is removed from the view, but 10019 is still on screen. To sum things up, the view does not adjust my changes until I refresh the page. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, your SELECT query is executed before your DELETE query, and therefore its results includes the subsequently-deleted bookmark.